# Two collection select in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models

```
City
belongs_to :country

Country
has_many :cities

User
belongs_to :city
```

In the user form i want to make two select, the first is to select a country

```
<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.all, :id, :name, options = {:prompt => 'Select a Country'}, html_options = {class:"form-control", required:true} %>
```

That work fine for me. But the problem is to select a city, i don't know how i can list only the cities of the selected country. I read about grouped_collection_select but i can't resolve my problem.

How can i do that? Thanks!

P.D: I don't want to use a gem.

---

I resolved the problem using grouped_collection_select

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :city_id, Pais.order(:name),:cities,:name, :id, :name, options = {:prompt => 'Select a City'}, html_options = {class:"form-control", required:true}%>
```

and jquery

```
$(function() {
    filterCitiesList();
})
function filterCitiesList() {
    $('#user_city_id').hide();
    users = $('#user_city_id').html();
    $('#user_country_id').change(function() {
        country_id = $('#user_country_id :selected').text();
        optgroup = "optgroup[label='" + country_id + "']"
        options = $(cities).filter(optgroup).html();

        if (country_id != "Select Country") {
            $('#user_city_id').show();
            $('#user_city_id').html(options);
        }
        else{
            $('#user_city_id').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Now i have another problem. I've modals windows, when i hide the Country modal i use

```
<%= select_tag "countries",options_from_collection_for_select(Country.all, "id", "name"), {id:"user_country_id", name:"user[country_id]",include_blank: 'Select Country', class: "form-control"}%>
```

### to render the country select. And the new question is How can i do that with grouped_collection_select?

I resolved the problem using option_groups_from_collection_for_select

```
<%= select_tag "cities",option_groups_from_collection_for_select(Country.order(:name), :cities, :name, :id, :name), {id:"user_city_id", name:"user[city_id]",include_blank: 'Select City', class: "form-control"} %>
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Do you want a unique select with nested countries and cities, or two selects, one with contries and the other one with cities ?

Comment: I want two selects, one per attribute.

Comment: So do you want the list of cities in your city_select to be updated each time you select a contry in your county_select ?

Comment: Just like that.. Do you know how do that?

Comment: There is no simple way to do that. You need a huge list of cities in the world per country. You can't just use two rails helpers which are intended to output selects and think that it will magically appear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve this with Ajax and Javascript.

1. User selects a country.
2. Send selected country id to the server.
3. Get corresponding cities by country id.
4. Refresh the cities select with the new results.

This is the basic idea.